# Enviar objetos maiores que 5 Gb utilizando SDK Amazon S3

Tags: java, web-service, amazon-aws

Há um tempo estou utilizando o SDK Amazon S3 para comunicações em um servidor em nuvem, chamado DreamHost ou DreamObjects.

A minha aplicação upa arquivos para minhas buckets. Porém, comecei a ter problemas pois meus arquivos ultrapassaram 5GB, e portanto, precisei mudar a forma de enviar o arquivo.
Segui a documentação disponibilizada no site da Amazon ([Documentação aqui](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html)).

Porém, ao utilizar essa maneira, obtenho o seguinte erro no console:

> dez 26, 2016 1:28:22 PM com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable performAbortMultipartUpload
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Unable to abort multipart upload, you may need to manually remove uploaded parts: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: tx0000000000000000f1f16-0058613740-12165497-default)
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: tx0000000000000000f1f16-0058613740-12165497-default), S3 Extended Request ID: 12165497-default-default

Porém, não sei o que seria esse "Signature". As minhas informações para acesso ao servidor estão ok, conferi por programas de terceiros e até mesmo no próprio site, então, não seria login/senha/autenticação.

Não sei como proceder. Alguém com alguma ideia que poderia me ajudar?
Abaixo, código que estou utilizando.

```
    try {
         AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(UploadBigFile.LOGIN_KEY, UploadBigFile.SECRET_KEY);             
         AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
         conn.setEndpoint("objects-us-west-1.dream.io");

         final File f = new File("C:\\backup\\packages.rar");             
         ObjectMetadata      metadata    = new ObjectMetadata();                          
         metadata.setContentLength(f.length());
         PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, "FOLDER NAME/cristiano - teste.zip", f);
         request.setGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            long transferidos         = 0L;                
            long transferidosParcial  = 0L;                
            long megaBytes            = 5000000L;
            long timeInicial          = System.currentTimeMillis();
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent pe) {
                transferidosParcial += pe.getBytesTransferred();
                transferidos        += pe.getBytesTransferred();                                        

                if (transferidosParcial >= megaBytes){
                    long timeFinal            = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeInicial;                                                 
                    int seconds = (int) (timeFinal / 1000) % 60 ;                                                                        

                    double transf       = transferidos/1024/1024;
                    double transParcial = transferidosParcial/1024/1024;
                    double arquivo = f.length()/1024/1024;
                    String tempo = calculeTotalTimeToUpload(seconds, transParcial, arquivo-transf);
                    System.out.println("Transferidos: "+transf+"(MB) de "+arquivo+". "+tempo);
                    transferidosParcial  = 0L;
                    timeInicial          = System.currentTimeMillis();

                }                  
            }
        }); 
        System.out.println("Enviando arquivo. Por favor, aguarde.");
        TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(conn);
        Upload upload = tm.upload(request);
        upload.upload.waitForCompletion();();
        System.out.println("Arquivo enviado com sucesso!");
    } catch (AmazonS3Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro 1");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AmazonClientException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro 2");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro 3");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Quase fiquei surdo!!! A tradução de é Assinatura.

Comment: Aparentemente o erro não é por causa do tamanho do arquivo. Veja aqui nesse link se te ajuda:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296999/status-code-403-signaturedoesnotmatch-when-i-am-using-amazon-ses

Comment: @AckLay Pois é, já tinha olhado esse tópico, mas não consegui extrair nada dele. E também, realmente não é sobre o problema do tamanho do arquivo, mas o AWS da amazon tem diferentes tipos de upload. Em baixo nível/alto nível, e para arquivos menores e maiores que 5GB. Menores que 5GG tenho uma rotina que está funcionando perfeitamente. Maiores que 5GB é essa desgraça ai que não funciona hahahah

Comment: Para arquivos menos que 5 Gb este código funciona? Ou você usa um arquivo diferente? Não é possível dividir tudo em arquivos menores do que 5 Gb cada e depois remontá-los quando for baixar eles?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim, é um código diferente e que funciona. O problema de dividir o arquivo é que é um arquivo de backup. Qualquer byte perdido, seria um desastre.  Já tive problemas de separação de arquivo que até desconheço, na qual, no computador do cliente, não separava os aquivos corretamente, e na minha sim. Então, estou tentando fugir dessa opção...

Comment: E se você enviar esse arquivo gigante de uma só vez para um outro local e de lá fizer o upload para a Amazon, pedaço por pedaço? Além disso, se algum byte for perdido, você pode utilizar alguns algoritmos de verificação de consistência para ter certeza que o que foi enviado está correto, e se não estiver, enviar de novo. Além disso, visto que é um backup, é importante que a máquina que esteja sendo copiada esteja realizando um número mínimo de operações de escrita em disco durante a operação.